# Plotly: How to rename legend elements of a plotly express stacked bar plot?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, legend, plotly-express

I use this example code given in plotly website.

```
import plotly.express as px
long_df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

This gives a plot like below.

[image]

**How can I rename the legends to replace gold, silver and bronze with first, second and third?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map the data to the values you want

```
import plotly.express as px
long_df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", 
             color=long_df["medal"].map({"gold":"first","silver":"second","bronze":"third"}), 
             title="Long-Form Input")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I often use this approach

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name]))
```

where names is a `dict`:

```
newnames = {'gold':'1', 'silver': '2', 'bronze':'3'}
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
long_df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.bar(long_df, x="nation", y="count", color="medal", title="Long-Form Input")

newnames = {'gold':'1', 'silver': '2', 'bronze':'3'}
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name]))

fig.show()
```